# Grab specific Info from txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have only experience with web scripting and cocoa (Mac), but not Windows programming, so I would be greatful for any help in producing a batch script or smt like that.
I have textfiles where there is information like this

```
AlexanderWelten*FI3FFK!duZ1
Daten: Alexander Welten<br />Abrahamstr. 22<br />18472 Berlin<br />Deutschland
Maddiiiiin*hg72152aaf
Daten: Martin Loob<br />Welzstr. 12<br />52621 Frankfurt<br />Deutschland
ricki1991*super112X
Daten: Lars Ulbrich<br />Azurstr. 51<br />72223 Bonn<br />Deutschland
......
```

The `"<br />"` can be ignored, it is not effective HTML, so no linebreak, I will replace it with `", "` anyway soon. 
Everytime there is "Daten: " I want to grab the postal and city from it and create a new txt file which should look like this:

```
18472 Berlin
52621 Frankfurt
72223 Bonn
......
```

Looking at my past Q&A it is obvious that my knowledge is in web based technologies.
I'd appreciate any help

***edit:*** 
postal and city are not always at the same "location", because sometimes there is an additional entry between street and postalcode/city. Example:

```
Susimega*hfu827aaa
Daten: Susi Lanzwelt<br />Mondstr. 16<br />bei Muellers<br />48812 Magdeburg<br />Deutschland
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easier than you seem to think:

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims=<>" %%a in (test.txt) do echo %%a
```

If you're going to replace `<br />` with a comma, use `"tokens=3 delims=,"`

(use `%a` instead of `%%a` if you use it on command line)

to process the additional entry:

```
(for /f "tokens=5,7 delims=<>" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  echo %%a|findstr /b "[0-9]">nul && echo %%a || echo %%b
)>output.txt
```

the trick: if token 5 starts with a number then echo token 5 else echo token 7

Comment: Interesting. I expected much more code. Works fine, but there is a small issue. I forgot to mention that sometimes there is an extra entry between "Street" and "plz city", in this case the wrong entry gets grabbed, I just tried it. Any idea how to fix this? (I made an edit in starting post to explain)

Comment: skip "bei Muellers" or add it to the output?

Comment: Thanks for answering Stephan. Right now it adds "bei Muellers" to the output - I only need PLZ and city

Comment: Thank you very much - now I understood the tokens thing. But sometimes instead of "bei Muellers" there is just "Muellers" :D in this case it doesnt work, I tried adding "6" to "tokens" but it didn't fix it. Also, how do I make an output not as echo but as a .txt file?

Comment: "Mueller" or "bei Mueller" shouldn't change anything, because both strings  don't start with a number. When parsing a text, analyzing it first is the most important thing. Might there be another additional field?. For printing to a file, just redirect the whole loop to a file (see my edit).

Comment: Sometimes instead of a name there is a number in it, sorry I mixed that up, for example I have an entry where there is just the number 26 in there, in this case the output is "26" and not the plz&city

Comment: I tried this `for /f "tokens=5,6,7 delims=<>" %a in (testparsing.txt) do ( echo %a|findstr /b "[0-9]">nul && echo %a || "[0-9]">nul && echo %b  || echo %c )`but it still shows "26" as output if the additional field is 26

Comment: `findstr /b /r /c:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] "` looks for exactly 5 numbers plus a space at the beginning (Paßt für Deutschland, aber nicht für z.B. Österreich - die haben 4stellige PLZ)

Comment: btw:  token 6 is `br \`

Comment: The grabbing works fine now, al least i havnt noticed any problem with the current list i tested :) thanks, but when using "(for...output) it also puts the Path and command for every single hit in the new txt file. Like this:
`C:/Users/Hans/Desktop(echo 22411 Wilhelmshaven findstr /b /r /c [............]
22441 Wilhelmshaven`
How is it possible to get clean list, with only plz and city each line

Comment: add `@echo off` to the beginning of your script. This supresses command repetition

Comment: for command line: `@(for /F "tokens=5,7 delims=<>" %a in (t.txt) do @echo %a  | findstr /b /r /c:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] "  1>nul  &&echo %a ||echo %b )>output.txt`

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm :)  Ich hab den ganzen Tag vorher nur im Inet nach irgendwelchen Text parsing tools abgesucht, war alles Müll.
Danke dir, Kollege

Comment: Es klappt zwar, aber ich würde das mit den token und so gerne etwas mehr verstehen. Kannst du mir das vllt an nem Beispiel erklären, wie wäre das z.B. wenn das Trennzeichen "-|-" anstatt "<br /> wäre?

Comment: `for` does only use characters as delimeters, not strings. For a detailed description see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: Hm okay, so if I would use ",- ", token must be "4"?

Comment: Attention, "Sabine Leutheusser-Schnarrenberger" could lead to mis-counts. Choose your delimiters wisely.